# AngularJS $Location.Path In Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application that needs to navigate to a different template when an event occurs.  This event could be triggered by the user clicking a button on the current AngularJS template, or it could be trigger by an AngularJS service that is periodically calling a web service to check for the event.

This AngularJS application actually has a number of events like this, so I created an AngularJS service to encapsulate the logic of what should happen when an event is fired.  It has a function for each event, and the AngularJS controller or the AngularJS service call this function when the event is fired.

The issue is when I call `$location.path` to navigate to the new template.  If it is called from a controller then an apply will already be in progress.  However is it is called from an AngularJS service then an apply will not already be in progress and I will need to call `$rootScope.$apply`.

My question is, how to I figure out when I need to call `$rootScope.$apply` and when I should not?  I looked at this website, https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js, and it passes in the `$scope` from the controller and looks at the `$$phase` object on the controllers scope to determine whether an apply is in progress.  However when I call this from another AngularJS service I will not have a controller `$scope` to pass in, so it does not work for me.

How can I make this work?  Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Here is some code to help explain what I am meaning.  The code shows an AngularJS service called 'eventsSrv' that has the logic for responding to events.  The 'eventsSrv' uses a service named 'monSrv' that I do not show the code for.  The 'monSrv' is responsible for picking up server events (by web sockets or polling a web service).  The 'eventsSrv' uses the 'monSrv' to know when the server fires an 'exit' event.

The code also shows a controller that calls the 'exit' function on the 'eventsSrv'.  In this simplified example it may not make sense to pull the 'exit' logic into s seperate service, but in the real life application the events have a lot more logic and can be called from various controllers.

The code below works when a server side event is raised by the 'monSrv' service.  However it does not work when the controller calls it because it says that and $apply is already in progress.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp');

    demoApp.factory('eventsSrv', ['$rootScope', 'monSrv', '$location', function ($rootScope, monSrv, $location) {
        factory.exit = function () {
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                $location.path('/exit');
            });
        };

        monSrv.onExit(function (event) {
            factory.exit();
        });

        monSrv.startListening();
        return factory;
    }]);

    demoApp.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', 'eventsSrv', function ($scope, eventsSrv) {
        $scope.exit = function () {
            eventsSrv.exit();
        };
    }]);

}());
```

Comment: please share some code here with us to see what's going on

Comment: You should not put the `$apply` inside the service. The one that calls the service from a context outside of Angular should wrap the service call in an `$apply`. Can you show an example of how the service is called and it doens't work without the `$apply`?